# Lazy loading from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, lazy-loading

I have some 4500 entries in my database. What is the best way to show them in a ListView. Should I load them all in one stretch when the application initializes or should I use lazy loading? The list will also be searchable and filterable. Could you also point me to some nice articles that would gimme a better idea. Please do give me suggestions.

Comment: I haven't used lazy loading before, please do point to articles that might be of help to me.

Comment: Given that it is a mobile application, you should definitely not load all the entries in one go... Use something algorithm to get ONLY the relevant data perhaps using a search, or some sort of pagination support for the data to acquire data by chunks of 20 - 50 rows at a time

Comment: Any resources I can refer to @Ranhiru Cooray

Comment: @RagunathJawahar Hi. I do have the same prob. I have like 1000 items in database and wanted all the items in a listView and the list view is both searchable and filterable. What approach did u follow.? is it good to have Lazy loading.? If yes, how can i achieve search and filter on ListView adapter on lazy loading.?

Comment: Use Commonsware's endless adapter to alleviate the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to [point you to here first](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) but I also have some experience I would like to share.

First, showing anything more than say 500 items in a list is probably going to cause users to complain (maybe not though). Users can get overwhelmed with info and it gets annoying for users to scroll to see all of the data (even with filters because some users will refuse to use them if they *can* scroll).

Second, the data adapter in Android is pretty smart so an adapter over thousands of items will be handled smoothly due to the way Android caches views and iterates through a result set with a cursor which is the subject of that link I pointed you to at the start of my answer.