# Android cursorLoader with pagination or load more functionality?

Tags: android, android-listview, pagination, loader, android-cursorloader

I have a huge amount of data in the sqlite database and I use android CursorLoader with ContentProvider to display them in the ListFragment. Well, it just load all the data to the list. My question is, how can I load the data with pagination? Or, just like when I scroll to the bottom of the list, it' ll load the next page' s items?

Comment: use lazy loading concept

Comment: can you give a example link? I have been searching for a long time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008875/lazy-loading-from-sqlite